# Difficulties understanding the mechanism of retrieving parameter values passed to a script in a function

Tags: syntax, autohotkey

The script passes two parameter values to another instance of the script. So the built-in parameter variable, 0, contains the number of passed parameters. 1 is in the below example "C:/Windows" and 2 is "/switchtest"

It is possible to assign the parameter values to strParam1 and strParam2 with the traditional method outside the function (with the single equal sign). However, inside a function, the assignments fail.

If they are assigned in a loop with the := sign, it seems to work.

Why is it? Can anybody explain this behavior?

```
strParam1 = %1%
strParam2 = %2%
msgbox, 64, Outside the Function, number of parameters:%0%`npath: %strParam1%`nswitch: %strParam2%
test_params()


strPath := "C:/Windows"
strSwitch := "/switchtest"
RunWait "%A_AhkPath%" "%A_ScriptFullPath%" "%strPath%" "%strSwitch%"


test_params() {
    global 0

    ; this works
    ; loop %0%
        ; strParam%A_Index% := %A_Index%

    ; this causes an error: "This dynamic variable is blank. If this variable was not intended to be dynamic, remove the % symbols from it."
    ; strParam1 := %1%
    ; strParam2 := %2%

    ; this passes empty values; however, this method works outside the function.
    strParam1 = %1%
    strParam2 = %2%

    msgbox, 64, Inside the Function, number of parameters:%0%`npath: %strParam1%`nswitch: %strParam2%
    if strParam2
        exitapp

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea with `global 0`; that allows %0% to carry into the function from toplevel. You just need to declare `global 1, 2` as well.

Even if you do this, you can't use `:=` to assign them to variables, because `:=` deals with expressions and there is no syntax to use them in expressions (normally a variable is referred to in an expression with the variable name alone, without `%%`; obviously `1` and `2` are interpreted as actual numbers instead of variables).

Comment: I don't get it. It doesn't explain why `global 1, 2` is not necessary if `loop %0%
        strParam%A_Index% := %A_Index%` is used.

Comment: In your head, replace 0, 1, and 2 with A, B and C.  If you say "global A", "B" and "C" aren't made global, because you didn't ask them to.

Comment: I'm afraid the question wasn't clear. I'd like to know why with a loop, it's not necessary to declare global for 1 and 2 but it is required for assignments in the traditional method.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, I would expect the variables to be assigned the literal values `1` and `2` inside the loop. That is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

@echristopherson answered the question, but I'd like to propose a workaround.  This assumes you're using AutoHotkey_L.

If you run the test script with the args "a b c", it gives you this.

```
3
1, a
2, b
3, c
```

The test:

```
argv := args()
test := argv.MaxIndex() "`n"

for index,param in argv
    test .= index ", " param "`n"

MsgBox % test
```

And the function:

```
args() {
    global
    local _tmp, _out

    _out := []

    Loop %0% {
        _tmp := %A_Index%
        if _tmp
            _out.Insert(_tmp)
    }

    return _out
}
```